# NWJS App routing works swell in dev, Build version doesn't routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, mern, nwjs

Currently working on a desktop app with NWJS. 
The stack I'm using is the MERN stack. I'm currently through the Building phase, and I have a major issue: my routes (with React-Router) don't work once the app is built.

You'll find screenshots of the problem below: at start my app is supposed to render a login form, (with react router).

I've tried most things, from refactoring, to getting rid of console warnings.. 
Yet everything in Dev works (through npm start). My Routing has no issues.. 
I just don't get it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import FormSignin from "./containers/form/form.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react- 
router-dom";
import Dashboard  from "./containers/dashboard/dashboard.js";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./components/PrivateRoute.js";
import LoaderApp from "./components/loader.js";
import Selector from "../src/components/selector";
import Footer from "../src/containers/footer";

class App extends Component {
  renderLoading() {
    return <LoaderApp />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
        <Selector/>
          <header className="App-header">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={FormSignin} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} 
            />
            </Switch>
          </header>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What is expected (working in dev) : [dev](https://i.ibb.co/xMmxCLg/nwjs-issue-2-dev.jpg)

What actually happens on prod build : [prodIssue](https://i.ibb.co/7CbgFYw/nwjs-issue-3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me finally.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import FormSignin from "./containers/form/form.js";
    import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import Dashboard  from "./containers/dashboard/dashboard.js";
    import { PrivateRoute } from "./components/PrivateRoute.js";
    import LoaderApp from "./components/loader.js";
    import Selector from "../src/components/selector";
    import Footer from "../src/containers/footer";

    class App extends Component {
      renderLoading() {
        return <LoaderApp />;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
            <Selector/>
              <header className="App-header">
                <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

                  <HashRouter>            
                    <Route exact path="/" component={FormSignin} />
                  </HashRouter>
                </Switch>
              </header>
              <Footer/>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```